# Groovy - How can I compare part of a list to a string

Tags: groovy, comparison

I have a list which contains two types of text. One type is used for authorization while other type is used for all other purposes.
The type used for authorization always uses the same text + some code after it.
I would like to compare content of these two types of text and separate them based on content.

My idea is to look for pattern in authorization type and if it matches the pattern then this would be marked as authorization, otherwise it would be marked as "other".

I researched about comparison of patterns in Groovy, but all variations I tried did not work for me. Here is the part which should do the comparison, I am obviously doing something wrong but I don't know what.

```
  jdbcOperations.queryForList(sql).collect { row ->
     if(assert (row['MSG'] ==~ /token/)){
  mark as authorization
 }
 else{
      mark as other
    }
  }
```

Sorry for the vague code, I can not share more than this.

Comment: I think the problem is in the very first line of your question: why do you have that list mixed together in the first place? That smells of bad design and (since you're talking about authorization) like the recipe of a security problem (when you have false positives or false negatives).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just missing the match for the rest of the text, since you are looking only for the first part to match.

```
assert ("abc" ==~ /abc/) == true
assert ("abcdefg" ==~ /abc/) == false
assert ("abcdefg" ==~ /abc(.*)/) == true // <--- This can also be made more complicated
```